# Custom Wordpress Post Page Breaks if More Than 2 Posts?

Tags: wordpress, templates, loops

I have a very custom template, and it works great if there are 1 or 2 posts on the blog page. But as soon as a 3rd post is added, it alters the structure of the template... Literally moves a div inside of another and I cannot understand why. The code for the blog template is here, and a screenshot of the structure as it should be and another showing the misplaced div when a third post is there. Does this make any sense, any ideas?

> 

```
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><!--start post-->

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <div id="main_full" class=" clearfix"><!--start main-->

            <div id="top_bar"><h3 class="gallery-title">news</h3></div>

                <div id="blog_page"><!--start blog page-->

                    <div class="entry"><!--start entry-->

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    </div><!--end entry-->

                </div><!--end blog page-->

        </div><!--end main-->

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div><!--end post-->

<?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the beginning of your loop, I can't be 100% sure, but it looks like you need to have:

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div><!--end post-->
```

be

```
     </div><!--end post-->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div><!--end post-->
```

Flip their places. If it doesn't help, please show us what while and what if are getting closed.

Comment: Weird sorry, that top empty gray box up there looks like it ate the first part of my code. It should show the loops open like so, 

<?php/*Template Name: Blog Postings Page*/?>
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: Yup, my solution will fix it.

Comment: Hmm odd. I made that change but no effect.  I am not sure what is updating now... I added a generic <h1>HERE!</h1> under the main div to see if it showed, and it does not appear. But altering the name of the template changes the template name used for the post.  I am confused.

Comment: We're going to need the full template file, cuz there are some other errors. 

But I'm pretty sure that the div, closing post should be BEFORE <?php endwhile; endif; ?>.